# Affine Transform Compatibility

Tags: java, animation

```
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        // draw background
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 700, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 500, null);
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 700, 500, null);

        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SPRITES; i++) {
            Sprite sprite = sprites[i];

            // translate the sprite
            transform.setToTranslation(sprite.getX(),
                sprite.getY());

            // if the sprite is moving left, flip the image
            if (sprite.getVelocityX() < 0) {
                transform.scale(-1, 1);
                transform.translate(-sprite.getWidth(), 0);
            }

            // draw it
            g.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), transform, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I was looking at a draw method in this class. The method is called with an animation loop, it draws a set of animated sprites on the screen that pass the method the correct frame in their animation depending on a timer. The sprites are also moving around the screen at a randomly generated velocity bouncing off the edges of the frame. Depending on whether they are traveling left or right the draw method transforms the image so the sprite is facing in the correct direction. All that transform information is contained in the transform for the drawImage method which I'm used to seeing as g.drawImage(Image, x, y, null); though obviously you can't do that here as you would lose the image flipping capabilities. Is there a way to do it though? Is there a way to transform the image scale but set its location by coordinate?

I ask because transforming is a more processors intensive activity and if lots of sprites need to be active at once it might really slow everything down. BONUS QUESTION: Is this a legitimate concern or should I not be too worried considering the strength of modern systems.

Comment: If I answer the bonus question, do I get extra credit?

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but what you're doing is fine. Transforms are (or can be) really elegant in general imo.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. What I'm asking is, is it possible to the first transform - the one that reverses the image - but then decide where the image is drawn based on coordinates?